# (uncaught exception)ReferenceError: gtag is not defined in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, uncaught-exception

Im new in cypress, trying to login to my practice web, but I got problem with this gtag. The actual testing with cypress is done (user success login) but there is one error that keeps make this testing failed, does anyone can help me?. this my pic and my cypress code and my config

This is my error pic

[image: 1]

```
describe('Login user', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(1392, 768)
    cy.visit('thiswebcom')

  })

  it('Login as user', () => {
    cy.get('a[href*="/login"]').first().click()
    cy.get('#buttonLoginTrack').should('have.text', '\n                                                        Login\n                                                    ')
    
    const userName = 'mymail@gmail.com'
    const password = 'mypassword'

    cy.get('#email').type(`${userName}`)
    cy.get('#password').type(`${password}`).type('{enter}')

  })
```

this is my cypress code for login in

```
module.exports = {
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here

    },
  },
};
```

this is my cypress.config.js file

I tried with blockHosts but no idea how to put it in, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Kitty.Flanagan's answer is a good one but should be cautious when using [`Cypress.on()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Cypress) as it will have a global impact, whereas [`cy.on()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#cy) will only persist for the test file.

Furthermore, returning false will bypass all uncaught exceptions and can lead to issues not being caught by your tests.

Ultimately, you want raise issues for any uncaught exceptions to your dev team. In the chance that the uncaught exception is something thrown by 3rd party and cannot be addressed, then I would suggest adding the following to your test file.

```
cy.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return !e.message.includes('ReferenceError: gtag is not defined in Cypress')
})
```

Comment: wow, thx for your correction, this is what Im using now

Comment: Does not really make sense to me, why would you catch one error but not another?

Comment: Third party integrations can throw uncaught exceptions, which don't typically interfere with the functional use. You can stub those integrations, when the test is not using that feature. Otherwise, catching exceptions by your app should be caught.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have "uncaught exception" in the picture there, it means that the application itself is creating that error - which is not visible to the user under normal circumstances unless you check for it in the devtools.

The trick is to put a catcher into the top of the test like this

```js
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false;
})
```

That stops the test from failing just because of a potentially harmless error in the app.

Here is some documentation: [Uncaught exceptions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Uncaught-Exceptions).

Generally speaking, as a tester you will be a bit worried about such an error, but it can't be fixed from the test, only from the application itself.

Comment: this is simple answer for any1 that understand, its work!, thank you very much

Comment: Change to `Cypress.once()` to handle the error one time only, then automatically switch off the catcher.