# Cypress cannot cy.visit() because page throws an uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, uncaught-exception

This error has prevented me from using cypress for months now

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('User login', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:8080')
  })
  // ...
})
```

i'm getting an error that says:

```
(uncaught exception)TypeError: Failed to set an indexed property on 'DOMStringList': Indexed property setter is not supported.
```

[image]

---

More details:

app specs:

- react 16.14.0
- react-router-dom 4.3.1
- react-redux ^5.0.4"

it seems the error is from something loading (assuming webpack)
`GET 200 /sockjs-node/info?t=1672024046431`

I notice if i comment out a specific component (the header bar) that the rest of the app seems to load

Comment: when you access http://localhost:8080 on browser, does it show that error?

Comment: @Damzaky it does not show that error on browser when navigating there on my own, no

Comment: Using [`cy.on()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74644380/17917809) would be a good choice here.

Answer (score 5):

When you see `(uncaught exception)` it's generally your app that is causing it.

You cannot change anything in the test code to actually fix it, which is pretty obvious since your test does not do anything except visit the page.

You can make Cypress turn a blind eye to this particular error by catching the `fail` event and returning `false` from inside the handler - that tells Cypress to carry on as if the error did not occur.

But now this is likely to be trouble later on, since it looks like the step is in authorization and you won't get very far without that.

The event catcher should be at the top of the spec and is this code:

```js
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', () => false)
```

If you find this is all that's needed, and you can test authorize correctly after that, then keep the code permanently but add a check for the specific error message

```js
Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', (err) => {
  if (err.message.contains('Failed to set an indexed property')) {
    return false
  }
})
```

But if you continue to get errors after this, I'm afraid you will have to post the React code to get a better answer.

Comment: unfortunately not working =( also tried adding `cy.on('uncaught:exception', e => false)` and that didnt work either. Went ahead and updated app specs, willing to answer more questions.

Comment: `cy.on('uncaught:exception')` is misleading, it can only be used in certain places. `Cypress.once('uncaught:exception')` will work if it's at the top of the test, or maybe the error occurs multiple times (you can't tell because the first one crashes the test), in which case change to `Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => false)` and it will swallow every uncaught exception the page throws.