# (uncaught exception)TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') type error while executing in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, typeerror, fixtures, uncaught-exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX77O.png)
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')
> When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.
> This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the uncaught:exception event.L

Comment: Can you see the bit that say's view call stack, don't use cypress but I've a feeling this will show you a callstack, these are very handy, try copy pasting the results into your question.  ps.  Don't use an image..

Comment: There might be a call to a third party service that has the uncaught error. You can either stub that to not be called our follow this answer with using cy.on() https://stackoverflow.com/a/74644380/17917809

Answer (score 3):

In the Cypress test you can add a line at the top that stops this error (in the app) from failing the test.

Of course, you will want to be sure that the error is not related to what you are testing.

The code would be

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => { return false })

cy.visit('/');
cy.get('#LoginUser').type('**')
cy.get('#password-field').type('**')
cy.get('#Login').click()

cy.contains('Dashboard')  // passes
```

The Cypress runner will still show the error in the log, but you can continue and test the page after login.

In this case, it looks like the error is caused by a missing element `#myPieChart`.